# Why does `this.refs` return undefined in this simple example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following example `this.refs.foo.clientWidth` returns `undefined` and I can't figure out why. How can I get the reference to `SomeComp` in `PageComp` to use its width? (using React 15.2.1 or similar)

```
class PageComp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs.foo.clientWidth);
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
      <p>{this.props.name}</p>
      <SomeComp ref="foo" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SomeComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>I loaded</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <PageComp name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/kohibiy/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Does `this.refs.foo` also log undefined?

Comment: It returns an object: http://jsbin.com/capelu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.refs.foo` returns React Element.
But if you want to work with DOM element - you need to find this Node

**React 15.0.1 Requires this syntax**: `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo)`

JSBIN:
http://jsbin.com/xabidaquti/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

For better clarity, `this.refs.foo.clientWidth` will work if the `refs` is set to html elements like `div`, `input` and so on. As `refs` by itself will return the DOM Node in case of such html elements.

If the `refs` is set to some React components, then we can access the DOM Node of the Components only using `ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo)` and hence we need to get the `clientWidth` using `ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo).clientWidth`.

[Ref](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5074)

Comment: I get an error if I use `this.refs.foo.getDOMNode().clientWidth` it sais: `TypeError: this.refs.foo.getDOMNode is not a function` See jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/vafedo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: the error was because the foo was pointing to Another react component and not a html element which has a DOM for ref: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5074

Comment: The error sais `getDOMNode is not a function` because it was deprecated and stopped working in v0.15. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["foo"].clientWidth)`

Comment: Incorrect closing bracket. It should be like this: `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["foo"]).clientWidth`

Comment: This doesn't address most parts of the question. Also, where should one try this? What does it do? How does it help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @dakab : Question is  `console.log(this.refs.foo.clientWidth);` - throws undefined. To make it work. `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo).clientWidth`